# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel fills up entire memory

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing, opencl

I am currently trying to write an OpenCL application doing some memory intensive calculations. To track the progress of all the calculations I created a **for loop which creates different kernel groups.** Unfortunately, the **calculation fills up my whole memory.** My guess is that the kernels are not done executing before the next heap is added.

```
for (unsigned long i=1; i<maxGlobalThreads; i+=1000000) {

    // Calculating Offset
    size_t temp = 1000000;
    size_t offset = 0;
    if (i>1000000) {
        offset = i-1000000;
    }

    cl_event tmp;

    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, &offset, &temp, NULL, NULL, 0, &tmp);

    // Wait until Threads finished (-- not working)
    clWaitForEvents(1, &tmp);

    // Copy results from memory buffer
    int *res = (int*)malloc(64*sizeof(int));
    int *indexNum = (int*)malloc(14*sizeof(int));
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, foundCombiMem, CL_TRUE, 0, 64*sizeof(int), res, 0, NULL, NULL);
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, indexNumMem, CL_TRUE, 0, 14*sizeof(int), indexNum, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Calculate Time for 1000000 checked combinations
    diff = clock() - start;
    double msec = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f\n", (msec/(i*1000000))*1000000);

    [ ... ]
}
```

[image: Memory Stats]

Comment: What do you do in the [...] parts?
Can you post the full code?

Comment: @DarkZeros I don't think the added code is really relevant, but I hope it gives a better overview.

Comment: If you are commenting this `clWaitForEvents(1, &tmp);` then you are queueing a big amount of jobs, that is filling up your memory.

Comment: @DarkZeros According to the OpenCL Documentation: "The function
cl_int clWaitForEvents (cl_uint num_events, const cl_event *event_list)
waits on the host thread for commands identified by event objects in event_list to complete." So there shouldn't be an issue with this line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing to mallocs that are never freed on each iteration of the loop. This is why you are running out of memory.

Also, your loop is using an unsigned int variable, which could be a problem depending on the value of maxGloablThreads.

Comment: You were really really close I forgot freeing one variable in the OpenCL application. Really stupid mistake. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best you can do is to add

```
clFinish(CommandQueue);
```

after

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
```